# __bridge_transfer and ABRecordCopyValue: and ARC

Tags: ios

I'm accessing the address book and have this line and am compiling using ARC:

```
 ABMultiValueRef phoneNums = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Does this line need to be rewritten as:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNums = (__bridge_transfer ) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

If yes then shouldn't the compiler have generated a warning?
If not then maybe I don't understand using ARC in conjunction with core framework thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not bridge in this case. `ABMultiValueRef` is a `CFTypeRef`. `ABRecordCopyValue` returns a `CFTypeRef`. There is no bridge required.

Bridge casting is required when you convert between `id` and `CFTypeRef` (which is a synonym for `void*`).

Comment: So ARC won't automatically release the ABMultiValueRef?

Comment: No. ARC only inserts `retain` and `release` calls for `id`. Nothing else. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC

Answer (score 2):

No, because you're not casting anything by making that assignment. You'll merely `CFRelease` the returned reference at a later time, as you do under the ordinary ownership rules.