# XCode Memory Leak Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, abrecord

I'm nearing the end of my project, though after Analyzing my project in XCode it is indicating to me that there is a memory leak at this line:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/uTkbA.png]

Here is the text version of the relevant code:

```
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString* firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);


    NSMutableString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

    //NSLog(@"%@", fullName);

    NSString* phoneNum = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers;
    phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                     kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
        phoneNum = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
    } else {
        phoneNum = @"Unknown";
    }

    NSLog(@"First name is %@ and last name is %@", firstName, lastName);
    NSLog(@"Phone is %@", phoneNum);

    phoneNum = [phoneNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    phoneNum = [phoneNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I don't believe it's crippling, but I don't want to give Apple a reason to reject my app from the store. Thank you.

Best...SL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `__bridge_transfer` everywhere except for the `phoneNumbers` return value from `ABRecordCopyValue`.

You need to transfer ownership of `phoneNumbers` to ARC or manually release the memory.

**UPDATE:** Having looked at this issue a bit closer I'm not sure you can transfer ownership to ARC, see [__bridge_transfer and ABRecordCopyValue: and ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217548/bridge-transfer-and-abrecordcopyvalue-and-arc) for more details.

Adding `CFRelease(phoneNumbers)` will manually release the memory.

For example:

```
NSString* phoneNum = nil;
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers;
phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                 kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phoneNum = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
} else {
    phoneNum = @"Unknown";
}

CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and correct response. I will mark this correct once the site lets me...